# InnoDB - roll back all transactions for connection

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is it possible to rollback all statements that have been executed in the same connection thread? Instead of ROLLBACK just reverting the last executed statement.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on *autocommit* which is disabled by default for each connection. From the [MySql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error. If a statement returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the error. See Section 13.2.12, “InnoDB Error Handling”.
>
> A session that has autocommit enabled can perform a multiple-statement transaction by starting it with an explicit START TRANSACTION or BEGIN statement and ending it with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK  statement.
>
> autocommit mode is disabled within a session with SET autocommit = 0, the session always has a transaction open. A COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement ends the current transaction and a new one starts.

You can't rollback statements if *autocommit* is enabled as the *commit* is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

Beside usual COMMIT and ROLLBACK statements, InnoDB supports [savepoints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/savepoint.html). Savepoints do allow  you to rollback only several last statements within the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot rollback things that are not in a transaction to begin with - although with most dbs you can have autocommit mode which makes each statement a transaction.

so to get what you want, you need to start a transaction, do whatever processing you need, and then rollback to the start, or commit.